# How to make bootstrap multiselect option connect with div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a multiselecor by using bootstrap multiselect. I want the options in the dropdown list connect with the div id. For example, when initialize and user does not make any selection, "chart 1", "chart 2" and "chart 3" are hidden on the webpage. If user selects option 1 and option 3, "chart 1" and "chart 3" show up.

I went through the tutorial on this website http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started. I am not sure if onChange funtion is the one to make this happen...If so, any other examples? I am a newbie for javascript and jquery.I am still not able to know how to do it after reading that website..Appreciate if you could give me more clue!!

The code below is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MultiSelect -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script ttype="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>    
    <div align="center" id="multiselect" multiple = "multiple" style = "display: none;">        
    </div>  
    <div id="chartId1"> 
        <b>'chart 1'</b>
    </div> 
    <div id="chartId2"> 
        <b>'chart 2'</b>
    </div> 
    <div id="chartId3"> 
        <b>'chart 3'</b>
    </div> 
    <script>    
function InitMultiselect(){
     var multiOptions = [
    {label: 'Option 1', value: '1'},
    {label: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
    {label: 'Option 3', value: '3'}
    ];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multiselect'). multiselect('dataprovider', multiOptions);

    });
}
InitMultiselect()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Bootstrap or that particular plug-in but based on the tutorial on that website, I think you are looking for something like this.

I made a JSFiddle but it includes JavaScript and CSS of that custom plug-in, so it might seem a bit confusing: https://jsfiddle.net/8qr4dtLy/1/

### HTML

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>

<div id="chartId1">
    <b>'chart 1'</b>
</div>
<div id="chartId2">
    <b>'chart 2'</b>
</div>
<div id="chartId3">
    <b>'chart 3'</b>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
#chartId1,
#chartId2,
#chartId3
{
  display: none;
}
```

---

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var multiOptions = [
        {
            label: 'Option 1',
            title: 'Option 1',
            value: '1'
        },
        {
            label: 'Option 2',
            title: 'Option 2',
            value: '2'
        },
        {
            label: 'Option 3',
            title: 'Option 3',
            value: '3'
        }];

    $('#multiselect').multiselect({
        onChange: function(option, checked, select)
        {
            var $element = $(option),
                value = $element.val(),
                divId = '#chartId' + value;

            $(divId).toggle($element.is(':selected'));
        }
    });

    $('#multiselect').multiselect('dataprovider', multiOptions);
});
```

---